# Change text in class with deferent text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with jQuery to append a different word at the end of each node with a same class ?

For example:

```
<p class="xyz">Some text</p>
<p class="xyz">Some another text</p>
<p class="xyz">Text somewhere</p>
```

would then be:

```
<p class="xyz">Some text word1</p>
<p class="xyz">Some another text word2</p>
<p class="xyz">Text somewhere word3</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Note that yes/no questions are not really suitable for Stack Overflow. You can ask those in chat. If you have a specific problem with your code, you are welcome to ask about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('.xyz').each(function(i){
    $(this).html($(this).html()+" word"+(i+1));//or  $(this).text($(this).text()+" word"+(i+1));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2urzk5d7/)**

Comment: why using `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: @Ramy: both will work.

Comment: True. though when doing text manipulation, I believe `text()` is more strict and IMHO it fits more for text manipulation to avoid changing the DOM in any unexpected way.

Comment: @Ramy: using `.html()` gets the inner HTML with markups, while `.text()` only gets the real displayed text. So strictly speaking, you should use `.text()` to prevent any DOM transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
$('.xyz').each(function(i){
  var count = i+1;
  $(this).html($(this).html()+ "word" + count)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9043kdn/1/